# Ubuntu AngularJS Grunt

Tags: angularjs, ubuntu, gruntjs

I was doing a small project using AngularJS in my Ubuntu OS. I used Yeoman to create the project and after writing some code, I started running the project using
      grunt serve
Everything was working fine, I got page displayed which was written using Angular.
I restarted the system due to some technical problems. grunt was not stopped before shut down. When I again run the grunt serve command, AngularJS based part of the web page is not showing. None of the angular code is working including routes. The folder 'bower_components' contains the angular header files. I found that none of them is loading. 
But when I started a simple HTML page containing a link to angular CDN, it works fine.

Comment: did you getting any error in browser console ? or in terminal  ?

Comment: Yes, there are errors in the console It says that some files for ui.bootstrap and ngGrid are missing. The problem is when I execute  'grunt serve' every time, 'index.html' loses some of the link and script tags. It creates the problem.

Comment: Now I force 'index.html' to have the previous contents by copying and pasting after a 'grunt serve' command. After doing this procedure, error is ''Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $$qProvider <- $$q <- $animate <- $compile''

Comment: Just delete all bower_components and nodes_modules and "npm install" / "bower install" it all ...